# Quickly and intuitively entering quantity and item

Tags: interaction-design, lists, input

I am trying to find an intuitive input control to create a list of `QUANTITY x ITEM` lines. The *items* already exist in the database and the simplest way to do this would be:

[image: mockup]

In order to make it faster to input the lines I thought about leaving it a plain text field that on `Enter` it would just add an `<li>` to a `<ul>` with a link to remove the line like so:

[image: mockup]

I am not so sure though how would the autocomplete work best and if there is a simple plugin like [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) that can accept free-form text ("3x") and autocomplete values ("Goblin") in a text input or a text area.

Comment: how many different types of items do you have?  who is the target user?

Comment: The target user is the typical D&D Dungeon Master (a geek and usually computer-savvy). The item types will have been entered by the user ahead of time and will usually enumerate in the few tens to about a couple hundreds.

Comment: Between typing "3x Goblin" into a single field, and typing "3" and "Goblin" into two separate fields, the latter is more efficient, no?  It requires one less key stroke, "TAB" vs "X"+"spacebar".  Otherwise I think your second mockup is about as efficient as you can get for keyboard entry

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered an autocomplete box and a list? The autocomplete box will ensure correct entry and the list will assist in managing the numbers.

I think if you allow users to enter free text then it adds one more element of difficulty on your side to parse and process the data. I like your idea of allowing free text so I think the autocomplete could be a compromise.

The list with buttons to incr/decr quantity is an idea I stole from online shopping sites. Also a delete/remove button could be included for each item.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnir7v.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Setting sensible defaults for item numbers can go a long way with this design (if they are applicable to your data, of course).  Kobolds may always come in bands of ten, but a dragon is a solitary beast :-)

Comment: The parsing part is easy (have done it before on an almost identical scenario). On your answer: the elements clutter of the shopping carts is what I am trying to avoid. That's why (on the second mockup) instead of having +/- controls near the quantity, I simply have a _remove_ link. Also, the list, in most cases, will have been thought of ahead in time so later adjustments will be rare.